# monster ai patrol and idle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, artificial-intelligence

I'm making a game with monsters (RPG) and what I would like to do is that the monster moves left and right (Patrol), and after waiting some random time it stands still (Idle).
So in the start the monster:

1. moves for like lets say 5 seconds,
2. then becomes Idle, and after Idling for lets say 3 seconds,
3. it moves again

do this process again and again infinitely, the code I wrote down here just keeps changing the Idle and Patrol each 1 second, I don't know, I hope you could help me figure it out, Thanks!

```
`using System.Collections; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using UnityEngine;

public class MonsterMove : MonoBehaviour { [SerializeField] private float 
MinPatrolTime, MaxPatrolTime, MinIdleTime, MaxIdleTime; [SerializeField] 
private bool ShouldBeIdle=false; public float MonsterMoveSpeed; public 
float Distance=2f; [SerializeField] private bool ShouldBePatroling = 
true; private bool MovingRight = true;

public Transform groundDetection;
private void Start()
{
}
private void Update()
{

}
 void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (ShouldBePatroling&&!ShouldBeIdle)
 {
     Move();
     StartCoroutine(PatrolTime());
 }
 else if (ShouldBeIdle==true&&!ShouldBePatroling) { //Idle Anim
     Debug.Log("Doing Idle Anim");
     StartCoroutine(IdleTime());
 }

 }
 void Move()
 {
 transform.Translate(Vector2.right * MonsterMoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
 int layer_mask1 = LayerMask.GetMask("Ground");
 RaycastHit2D groundInfo = Physics2D.Raycast(groundDetection.position, 
 Vector2.down, Distance, layer_mask1);
 if (groundInfo.collider == false)
 {
     if (MovingRight == true)
     {
         transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, -180, 0);
         MovingRight = false;
     }
     else
     {
         transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
         MovingRight = true;
     }
     }
  }
   IEnumerator PatrolTime()
 {
 yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(MinPatrolTime, 
 MaxPatrolTime));
 ShouldBePatroling = false;
 ShouldBeIdle = true;
 }
  IEnumerator IdleTime()
 {
 yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(MinIdleTime, MaxIdleTime));
 ShouldBePatroling = true;
 ShouldBeIdle = false;`
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In you `FixedUpdate` you are starting coroutines even when already started coroutines are still running, thus messing up your state variables.
You could introduce further state variables to check whether the monster is currently already moving / idle, so no coroutine needs to be started. If you use an `enum` instead multiple `bools` (see the [state pattern](https://www.habrador.com/tutorials/programming-patterns/6-state-pattern/)), this could look like the following:

```
public class MonsterMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    ...

    protected enum State
    {
        Idle,
        StartPatrolling,
        Patrolling,
        StopPatrolling,
    }
    protected State state = State.StartPatrolling;

    ...

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        switch (state)
        {
            case State.StartPatrolling:
                {
                    StartCoroutine(PatrolTime());
                    state = State.Patrolling;
                    break;
                }
            case State.StopPatrolling:
                {
                    StartCoroutine(IdleTime());
                    state = State.Idle;
                    break;
                }
            case State.Patrolling:
                {
                    Move();
                    break;
                }
            case State.Idle:
                {
                    // nothing to be done
                    break;
                }
        }
    }

    ...

    IEnumerator PatrolTime()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(MinPatrolTime, MaxPatrolTime));
        state = State.StopPatrolling;
    }

    IEnumerator IdleTime()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(MinIdleTime, MaxIdleTime));
        state = State.StartPatrolling;
    }
}
```

Furthermore you seem to switch the direction in your `Move` method when there is no collision, which you might want to change to when there is a collision (see the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit2D-collider.html)):

```
if (groundInfo.collider != null)
```